# If I'm using storybook for my react project can I remove this from my js bundle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bundle, storybook

is it a good idea to remove react storybook from the JS bundle? obviously it isn't needed for any client facing part of my apps. so should I remove it from the bundle for the app and include it in the storybook bundle?

Comment: Storybook should definitely not be included in your client side bundle. It probably should be in a seperate project all together

Answer (score 3):

According to their official documentation, we should use `npx sb init`.
When checking the package.json file of the frontend project, this will install storybook under the dev-dependencies. https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install

Hence, when creating a production build (such as with `npm run build` under create-react-app), it will automatically be excluded in the bundle.